# php file is not redirecting through javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have used jquery for validating my login page. After submitting my login page it comes to the following php file so far it is ok.From this page if login details are correct then it should redirect to my dashboard.php(different page) . But it is not redirecting and it is giving the target file content into the same page(login page) itself after login form.here my code

```
/*admin_login_back.php*/


<?php

@session_start();

include_once("conn.php");


  $uname=$_POST['uname'];

  $pass=$_POST['password'];

  if($uname=="" || $pass=="")

  {

   echo "please enter username and password";

  }

  $sql="select *from admin where username='$uname' and password='$pass' limit 1";

  $res=mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_errno().'='.mysql_error());

  if(mysql_affected_rows()>0)

  {

       $_SESSION['uid']=$uname;
       header("Location:dashboard.php");


  }

  else

{

   echo "The username and password u entered is wrong";

  }

?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Format your code and your text properly and I may consider to answer your question.

Comment: why you need "./" before the page name??

Comment: Do as BotskoNet suggested, it is most reasonable

Answer (score 2):

If you're already using PHP, don't use javascript to handle the redirect, just do it directly through php:

```
header("Location: someurl.php");
```

Just make sure the `header` call is prior to any actual output from the php script.

Comment: i have tried this one also .When using header the problem is it is giving the content of dashboard.php in the login page itself after the login form.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. The header redirect will actually send the user to a different page, it can't cause two to display to together unless you're using iframes or something.

Comment: No Iam not using any iframes in my code.Even i have worked with headers before and those were worked properly.Iam wodering about this displaying content on the same page without going to diff page.I have used jquery for posting the login data.If i entered wrong input it is giving me the error on the same login page so it works properly.But when i enter correct input it giving this type of

Comment: You asked to direct the user to a different page, that's what I explained how to do. What are we missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the load2() function isn't being called. Also it seems that you're missing the  and  tags, so your javascript code is not being parsed/executed correctly. Try the following:

```
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    window.location = './dashboard.php';
  };
</script>
```

Also it's better to use a HTTP redirect, you can do that with just-PHP:

```
<?php
  header( "Location: dashboard.php" );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please enable the error reporting by adding the following line in beginning of the page.

```
 ini_set("display_errors",1);
```

It should display the error like **headers already sent**. If any errors shows like that please add the following output buffer code or remove the echo before the header

```
ob_start();
```

Comment: target file means dashboard.php file contents right??

Comment: yes.it showing the dashboard.php content.As i stated iam using jquery+Ajax for validating the login details within the same page

Comment: ok then you do something instead of using header in php return some text like "redirect" to the login page through ajax and inside that success of the ajax check the returned data from the "php" if it is a text like "redirect",do the redirection using javascript i.e., window.location = dashboard.php ... Have u tried this??

Comment: can u provide ur mail address i will send the code just a glance on code please....

Comment: ya sure kalai06cs19@gmail.com